# Facebook API and Facebook Connect using Java?

Tags: java, facebook

New to Facebook API and Facebook Connect.

Found the [Facebook Java API](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api) open source library on Google Code...

I am really excited that there's an API pre-written in Java for it!

Am interested in writing a server side Java layer which uses REST to be able to access a user’s Facebook Friends List, their wall, send them messages in-network, etc.

Downloaded the binary and unfortunately, I haven't found any sample or demo code when I unzipped it...

Question(s):

(1) Does this library support Facebook Connect?

(2) What is the best way to get start using Facebook Connect with server side Java?

(3) Since I am building middleware, do I still have to create a sample app on the online Facebook Developer page?

(4) What should I include in my (am a newbie in Maven) pom.xml in order to get started?

Comment: Only know the answer to #3: yes, because you need an API key to use any of the Facebook API functions.

Comment: If you can't find the answers in the library, you might want to consider using another library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, that library is broken.  I couldn't get authentication to work with the latest version.
In my search for alternatives i found the "TinyFBTagLibrary" http://www.socialjava.com/  --
Yes, it requires just about a billion extra libraries to run, but it offers a simple way to execute facebook API calls in java that ISNT BROKEN (once again, as far as I know).  My advice is to ignore all of the predefined tags for use in jsp and scroll down to the bottom to see how to use the TinyFBClient.call/getResponse when you need to get information.

Comment: additionally, the FB connect authentication is done with a simple call to the facebook connect javascript library, which then stores a session key in a cookie accessible by your server, and subsequently usable with the API

Comment: Sam and jimyi!

Thanks for the information... I think I am going to use the Facebook Connect library for iPhone instead.

Answer (score 17):

Use RestFB, that seems to be the inofficial FB Java Api:

http://restfb.com/

(There is no official FB Java Api anymore)