# Simplest way to read JSON from a URL in Java

Tags: java, json, url

This might be a dumb question but what is the simplest way to read and parse **JSON** from **URL** in **Java**?

In Groovy, it's a matter of few lines of code. Java examples that I find are ridiculously long (and have huge exception handling block).

All I want to do is to read the content of [this link](https://graph.facebook.com/me).

Comment: The exception handling is required as java forces you to handle any exceptions that are declared. What's wrong with exception handling?

Comment: well, the "java force you" is the biggest problem

Comment: If java didn't force you to handle exceptions do you think programs would still run and run well? What if I was asked to input my age into a program and I gave snarfleblagger as my input? Should java allow the program to just execute with no issues? If you don't want to handle exceptions then declare them as being thrown by the methods that they may occur in and watch your program fail when something isn't perfectly right.

Comment: Not a dumb question at all. Especially coming from PHP where you can do this with `json_decode(file_get_contents($url));` and be done!

Answer (score 227):

Using the Maven artifact `org.json:json` I got the following code, which I think is quite short. Not as short as possible, but still usable.

```
package so4308554;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonReader {

  private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552");
    System.out.println(json.toString());
    System.out.println(json.get("id"));
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize it was that easy to create an input stream from a url.

Comment: instead of reading character by character you can use readLine() on BufferedReader. This will reduce the number of iterations of while loop.

Comment: What for? The `readLine` function will do the loop then, and I have to concatenate the lines instead of the characters, which is more expensive. That wouldn't keep the code as short as it is now. Furthermore, in JSON notation there is no concept of "lines", so why should I read them as such?

Comment: Reading content as String is unnecessary; instead just use InputStream, pass to a GOOD JSON lib (i.e. not org.json lib)

Comment: Consider Apache commons-io's `IOUtils.toString(InputStream)` method. That should save you some lines and responsibility.

Comment: Why i am getting this error "The constructor JSONObject(String) is undefined" in the line of JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText); in "readJsonFromUrl" method..? @RolandIllig

Comment: With GSON, Jackson, Boon, Genson and others, you only need to feed the source: either just URL, or at most `InputStream`. While code above may be short for `org.json` usage, make sure to verify other libs available -- there is no need to write more than 1-3 lines of code for this task.

Comment: @Karthick pop, I got this Exception, it seems that eclipse had automatically imported `net.minidev.json.JSONObject` which does not have the JSONObject(String) constructor. The correct class for this code is: `org.json.JSONObject`

Comment: I have this error when i try to execute the code `java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Unhandled exception type IOException
 Unhandled exception type JSONException`

Answer (score 74):

Here are couple of alternatives versions with [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) (since there are more than one ways you might want data as):

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // just need one
  // Got a Java class that data maps to nicely? If so:
  FacebookGraph graph = mapper.readValue(url, FaceBookGraph.class);
  // Or: if no class (and don't need one), just map to Map.class:
  Map<String,Object> map = mapper.readValue(url, Map.class);
```

And specifically the usual (IMO) case where you want to deal with Java objects, can be made one liner:

```
FacebookGraph graph = new ObjectMapper().readValue(url, FaceBookGraph.class);
```

Other libs like Gson also support one-line methods; why many examples show much longer sections is odd. And even worse is that many examples use obsolete org.json library; it may have been the first thing around, but there are half a dozen better alternatives so there is very little reason to use it.

Comment: What is url here? Is it a string or URL object or byte[]?

Comment: I was thinking of `java.net.URL` but either one works, as well as plenty of other sources (`File`, `InputStream`, `Reader`, `String`).

Comment: It _should_ be java.net.URL in the example above, otherwise it will try to parse string 'http://....' as a json, which will yield an error

Comment: @Zotov Yes. Passing `String` would require contents to be JSON, and not textual encoding of URI/URL to use.

Comment: Unrecognized token 'https': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Comment: @DamirOlejar yes. That's what it says: you are passing URL as _JSON Content_, something it is not. So that error is exactly as expected. If you want to pass URL _as source_, you must pass `java.net.URL` value, not `String`. `String` means JSON content.

Comment: @StaxMan the sole link is broken which is why it is a good idea to summarize a bit of the link because they often break. Also I'm not sure what **Facebook** is doing in your answer?

Answer (score 72):

The easiest way: 
Use gson, google's own goto json library. https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Here is a sample. I'm going to this free geolocator website and parsing the json and displaying my zipcode. (just put this stuff in a main method to test it out)

```
    String sURL = "http://freegeoip.net/json/"; //just a string

    // Connect to the URL using java's native library
    URL url = new URL(sURL);
    URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
    request.connect();

    // Convert to a JSON object to print data
    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
    JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
    JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object. 
    String zipcode = rootobj.get("zip_code").getAsString(); //just grab the zipcode
```

Comment: Why i'm getting the 'NetworkOnMainThreadException' error? I must user an AsyncTask or there is another way? In this example did you get this error too?

Comment: Typo, should be: `rootobj.get("zip_code").getAsString();`

Comment: How do i import the jsonParser? I always get the error: 'Error:(69, 9) error: cannot find symbol class JsonParser'

Comment: Please add maven dependency  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>    to get the JsonParse in your pom file.

Comment: can be simplified and handled in a typesafe way with Gson like:
MyResponseObject response = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()), MyResponseObject.class);

Comment: Refer to [official documentation](https://github.com/google/gson) and [user guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) for updates. Example code here uses deprecated features of Gson.

Comment: @Benetz That's because you do it on the main thread (AKA UI thread). Do it in a background thread instead.

Comment: @androiddeveloper thanks for your answer, but 5 years have passed, I don't even remember what I was working at the time ;)

Answer (score 56):

If you don't mind using a couple libraries it can be done in a single line.

Include [Apache Commons IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) & [json.org](http://www.json.org/java/) libraries.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me"), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @andrdoiddev - You should ask that as a separate question.  It is more general to Apache Commons, Gradle and Android Development.

Comment: This is quite old now, but is still a good solution, so just in case @andrdoiddev or anyone else still needs the Gradle dependencies, these are the ones I'm using:

compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'

Comment: Say you are firing multiple requests, saving the json responses to a JSONArray and then writing the JSONArray to a file using FileWriter, then this library DOES NOT ESCAPE double quotes. This makes the file be easily parsed back to JSONArray.

Comment: Thanks @Irregardless, looks like json.org re-worked their packages.  There is no longer a default reference java implementation on their site.  I will update the link to use the first java project in their list of java libraries on their home page https://json.org/ as that should work and be compatible as it's a reference implementation.

Comment: retrieves a null exception, is not a solution

Answer (score 6):

Use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) to grab the contents of the URL.  And then use the library from [json.org](http://json.org) to parse the JSON.  I've used these two libraries on many projects and they have been robust and simple to use.

Other than that you can try using a Facebook API java library.  I don't have any experience in this area, but there is a question on stack overflow related to [using a Facebook API in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360060/facebook-api-and-facebook-connect-using-java). You may want to look at [RestFB](http://restfb.com/) as a good choice for a library to use.

Answer (score 6):

I have done the json parser in simplest way, here it is

```
package com.inzane.shoapp.activity;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        System.out.println("error on parse data in jsonparser.java");
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

this class returns the json object from the url

and when you want the json object you just call this class and the method in your Activity class

my code is here

```
String url = "your url";
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject object = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
String content=object.getString("json key");
```

here the "json key" is denoted that the key in your json file

this is a simple json file example

```
{
    "json":"hi"
}
```

Here "json" is key and "hi" is value

This will get your json value to string content.

Answer (score 5):

I have found this to be the easiest way by far.

Use this method:

```
public static String getJSON(String url) {
        HttpsURLConnection con = null;
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) u.openConnection();

            con.connect();


            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();
            return sb.toString();


        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And use it like this:

```
String json = getJSON(url);
JSONObject obj;
   try {
         obj = new JSONObject(json);
         JSONArray results_arr = obj.getJSONArray("results");
         final int n = results_arr.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                // get the place id of each object in JSON (Google Search API)
                String place_id = results_arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("place_id");
            }


   }
```

Comment: You have got a ClassCastException exception sitting in there.                                                  
Change the line                                                                                                                                 
URL u = new URL(url);
to this
URL u = new URL(null, url, new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());
for this code to work

Answer (score 5):

The Oracle Documentation describes how

1. an [HttpRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html) is built and then
2. sent by the HttpClient to the URL

in just a few lines of code, by **using only the Java Class Library**. Put this code into your main method:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
      .uri(URI.create("http://example.com/"))
      .build();
client.sendAsync(request, BodyHandlers.ofString())
      .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
      .thenAccept(System.out::println)
      .join();
```

The response consists of a JSON object { ... } and can be further processed in your application.
Here I printed it to the console, just to confirm it works:

```
System.out.println(request);
```

This is available for Java Versions 11+

Answer (score 4):

It's very easy, using jersey-client, just include this maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then invoke it using this example:

```java
String json = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json").request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
```

Then use Google's Gson to parse the JSON:

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type gm = new TypeToken<CoinDeskMessage>() {}.getType();
CoinDeskMessage cdm = gson.fromJson(json, gm);
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add an updated answer here since (somewhat) recent updates to the JDK have made it a bit easier to read the contents of an HTTP URL.
Like others have said, you'll still need to use a JSON library to do the parsing, since the JDK doesn't currently contain one. 
Here are a few of the most commonly used JSON libraries for Java:

- [org.JSON](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/)
- [FasterXML Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)
- [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

To retrieve JSON from a URL, this seems to be the simplest way using strictly JDK classes (but probably not something you'd want to do for large payloads), Java 9 introduced: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes()

```java
try(java.io.InputStream is = new java.net.URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me").openStream()) {
    String contents = new String(is.readAllBytes());
}
```

To parse the JSON using the GSON library, for example

```java
com.google.gson.JsonElement element = com.google.gson.JsonParser.parseString(contents); //from 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is efficient, but this is one of the possible ways:

Read json from url use `url.openStream()` and read contents into a string.

construct a JSON object with this string (more at [json.org](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html))

```
JSONObject(java.lang.String source)
      Construct a JSONObject from a source JSON text string.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full sample of how to parse Json content. The example takes the Android versions statistics (found from Android Studio source code [**here**](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/studio-master-dev:tools/adt/idea/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/stats/DistributionService.java), which links to [**here**](https://dl.google.com/android/studio/metadata/distributions.json)).

Copy the "distributions.json" file you get from there into res/raw, as a fallback.

**build.gradle**

```
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

**manifest**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            return
        thread {
            // https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/studio-master-dev:tools/adt/idea/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/stats/DistributionService.java
            var root: JsonArray
            Log.d("AppLog", "loading...")
            try {
                HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true)
                val statsUrl = "https://dl.google.com/android/studio/metadata/distributions.json" //just a string
                val url = URL(statsUrl)
                val request: HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                request.connectTimeout = 3000
                request.connect()
                InputStreamReader(request.content as InputStream).use {
                    root = JsonParser.parseReader(it).asJsonArray
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("AppLog", "error while loading from Internet, so using fallback")
                e.printStackTrace()
                InputStreamReader(resources.openRawResource(R.raw.distributions)).use {
                    root = JsonParser.parseReader(it).asJsonArray
                }
            }
            val decimalFormat = DecimalFormat("0.00")
            Log.d("AppLog", "result:")

            root.forEach {
                val androidVersionInfo = it.asJsonObject
                val versionNickName = androidVersionInfo.get("name").asString
                val versionName = androidVersionInfo.get("version").asString
                val versionApiLevel = androidVersionInfo.get("apiLevel").asInt
                val marketSharePercentage = androidVersionInfo.get("distributionPercentage").asFloat * 100f
                Log.d("AppLog", "\"$versionNickName\" - $versionName - API$versionApiLevel - ${decimalFormat.format(marketSharePercentage)}%")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As alternative to the dependency, you can also use this instead:

```
InputStreamReader(request.content as InputStream).use {
    val jsonArray = JSONArray(it.readText())
}
```

and the fallback:

```
InputStreamReader(resources.openRawResource(R.raw.distributions)).use {
    val jsonArray = JSONArray(it.readText())
}
```

The result of running this:

```
loading...
result:
"Ice Cream Sandwich" - 4.0 - API15 - 0.20%
"Jelly Bean" - 4.1 - API16 - 0.60%
"Jelly Bean" - 4.2 - API17 - 0.80%
"Jelly Bean" - 4.3 - API18 - 0.30%
"KitKat" - 4.4 - API19 - 4.00%
"Lollipop" - 5.0 - API21 - 1.80%
"Lollipop" - 5.1 - API22 - 7.40%
"Marshmallow" - 6.0 - API23 - 11.20%
"Nougat" - 7.0 - API24 - 7.50%
"Nougat" - 7.1 - API25 - 5.40%
"Oreo" - 8.0 - API26 - 7.30%
"Oreo" - 8.1 - API27 - 14.00%
"Pie" - 9.0 - API28 - 31.30%
"Android 10" - 10.0 - API29 - 8.20%
```