# JSON Parsing Exception in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, jsonexception

I have the following problem:
I have a JSON File on a Server which I try to parse in Android. But i get the following error message:

> 06-13 19:24:39.025: E/JSON Parser(17169): Error parsing data
>   org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿ of type java.lang.String cannot be
>   converted to JSONObject

Here is my JSON File:

```
    {
"settings":[
  {
     "rss":"true",
     "rss_feed":"http://test.com/rss.rss"
  }
],
 "map_locations":[
  {
     "title":"Büro Toronto",
     "address":"123 Younge Street Toronto"
  },
  {
     "title":"Büro New York",
     "address":"Time Square New York"
  }
]
}
```

And this is my Code:

```
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(SETTINGS_URL);

        try {
            JSONObject c = json.getJSONArray("settings").getJSONObject(0);

            rss = c.getBoolean("rss");

            JSONArray jMap = json.getJSONArray("map_locations");
            for (int i = 0; i < jMap.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c2 = jMap.getJSONObject(i);

                String map_title = c2.getString("title");
                String map_address = c2.getString("address");

                mapListTitle.add(map_title);
                mapListAddress.add(map_address);
            }

            URL_TO_RSSFEED = c.getString("rss_feed");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

The strange thing is that I didn't change anything (At my knowdledge) and it did work before.
If you need any more information let me know!

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Like UTF-8 problems or something? I also tried it with "ue" instead of "ü" but that didn't change anything...

Comment: @user754730 : you can check json return by api is valid or not from here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: The JSON actually looks fine on the website there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow ok I found the answer... Had to change

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
```

to

```
to BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
```

Strange enought it did work a few hours before with the same settings.

But thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code and it runs fine.

```
String jsonStr = "{\"settings\":[{\"rss\":\"true\",\"rss_feed\":\"http://test.com/rss.rss\"}],\"map_locations\":[{\"title\":\"Büro Toronto\",\"address\":\"123 Younge Street Toronto\""
              +"},{\"title\":\"Büro New York\",\"address\":\"Time Square New York\"}]}";
    try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


        JSONObject c = json.getJSONArray("settings").getJSONObject(0);

        boolean rss = c.getBoolean("rss");

        JSONArray jMap = json.getJSONArray("map_locations");
        for (int i = 0; i < jMap.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c2 = jMap.getJSONObject(i);

            String map_title = c2.getString("title");
            String map_address = c2.getString("address");

           /* mapListTitle.add(map_title);
            mapListAddress.add(map_address);*/
        }

       String URL_TO_RSSFEED = c.getString("rss_feed");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

So I can only conclude that there might be some errors in the first `jsonObject` you are creating and I am talking about this line:

`JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(SETTINGS_URL);`

Comment: I presume you might be using the `readJsonFromUrl(String url)` from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308554/simplest-way-to-read-json-from-a-url-in-java , the answer given by @RolandIllig. If yes, then you are getting in the error at this line `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);`.

Comment: Thanks that's what made me have a look inside my JSONParser class. You find my solution below.