# How do i used json parsing for two user enter city in edittext for finding lat long?

Tags: android

I am trying to draw the route on Google map in android for two location and distance between them which is enter by user in two edit-text so what should   i do for this please tell me.

Thank you

Comment: What you tried till?

Comment: Post some of your code, so we can know atleast.

Comment: Draw Path on Google Maps Android API get lat lang af address and pass http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api/

Comment: i have code for one city but i want to do same for secod city

Comment: @Piush yes i google but i got code only for single city i want for two city

Comment: @Remees i tried using geocoder but its not working and using json i have code for only one city

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Reverse Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to get latitude-longitude from address.

Check Example here : [Get latitude,longitude from address in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835426/get-latitude-longitude-from-address-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Android draw route between two geo location MapV2

http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-draw-route-between-two-geo.html

Comment: this is answer of this question can give address and get path direcet have u any methed to create route between two address

Comment: @Naveen i want to draw the path between two city which is enter by user in ediitext like pune to mumbai or whatever it may be

Comment: have u know how to get lat lang by address

Comment: read the link properly ... there is method to draw

  PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(10).color(
                              Color.RED);

                  for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
                        rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
                  }
                  // Adding route on the map
                  mGoogleMap.addPolyline(rectLine);

Comment: @Naveen yes by using two way geocoder and using url request json parsing bt geocoder is not working for me and i am new for json

Comment: pass lat lang to this http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api/

Comment: @Naveen bt how to get lat long for two city enter in two edittext

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835426/get-latitude-longitude-from-address-in-android

Comment: @Naveen thank for your help but i m so new for jason so i m not getting it

Comment: er.naveen.tamrakar@gmail.com can also chat me on this id