# Google+ public API keys doesn't work in Android app (it works in browser)

Tags: android, json, api, google-plus, public

I have a browser and a android key for Google+ public API. Both work perfectly in browser (Chrome), but I get this error when I use inside the app:

```
    01-23 21:31:56.348    2645-2657/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 9.048ms
01-23 21:31:56.351    2645-2657/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3019(153KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free, 9MB/13MB, paused 32.687ms total 37.855ms
01-23 21:31:56.368    2645-2663/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
01-23 21:31:56.368    2645-2645/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c473c0, tid 2645
01-23 21:31:56.488    2645-2645/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
01-23 21:31:56.537    2645-2663/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c47e00, tid 2663
01-23 21:31:56.586    2645-2663/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-23 21:31:56.594    2645-2661/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions E/JsonParser.java﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Not of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-23 21:31:56.594    2645-2661/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions, PID: 2645
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions.MainActivity$AsyncTaskParseJson.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:134)
            at com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions.MainActivity$AsyncTaskParseJson.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:114)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
01-23 21:31:56.612    2645-2663/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-23 21:31:56.620    2645-2663/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-23 21:31:56.621    2645-2663/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c9da80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-23 21:37:19.786    2702-2702/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions E/libprocessgroup﹕ failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system
01-23 21:37:19.786    2702-2702/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions W/Zygote﹕ createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
01-23 21:37:19.786    2702-2702/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-23 21:37:19.974    2702-2714/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 124(5KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 2MB/2MB, paused 11.319ms total 24.560ms
01-23 21:37:20.055    2702-2714/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 188(29KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 30% free, 9MB/13MB, paused 11.827ms total 27.957ms
01-23 21:37:20.106    2702-2719/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
01-23 21:37:20.108    2702-2702/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa68493c0, tid 2702
01-23 21:37:20.144    2702-2702/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
01-23 21:37:20.175    2702-2719/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6849730, tid 2719
01-23 21:37:20.195    2702-2719/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-23 21:37:20.216    2702-2719/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-23 21:37:20.224    2702-2719/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-23 21:37:20.224    2702-2719/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa68a43a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-23 21:37:20.408    2702-2718/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions E/JsonParser.java﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Not of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-23 21:37:20.408    2702-2718/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions, PID: 2702
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions.MainActivity$AsyncTaskParseJson.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:135)
            at com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions.MainActivity$AsyncTaskParseJson.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:114)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
01-23 21:47:55.916    2760-2760/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions E/libprocessgroup﹕ failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system
01-23 21:47:55.916    2760-2760/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions W/Zygote﹕ createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
01-23 21:47:55.917    2760-2760/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-23 21:47:56.129    2760-2778/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
01-23 21:47:56.131    2760-2760/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c463d0, tid 2760
01-23 21:47:56.176    2760-2760/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
01-23 21:47:56.230    2760-2778/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c46ce0, tid 2778
01-23 21:47:56.310    2760-2778/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-23 21:47:56.352    2760-2778/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-23 21:47:56.369    2760-2778/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-23 21:47:56.369    2760-2778/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c9efa0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-23 21:47:56.442    2760-2776/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions E/JsonParser.java﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Not of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-23 21:47:56.442    2760-2776/com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions, PID: 2760
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions.MainActivity$AsyncTaskParseJson.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:134)
            at com.example.javier.NavigationDrawerAllVersions.MainActivity$AsyncTaskParseJson.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:114)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The code is working perfectly with others json objects...
This is the json object that I get on browser with bot keys:

```
{
 "kind": "plus#person",
 "etag": "\"RqKWnRU4WW46-6W3rWhLR9iFZQM/bL-xcqP0OC4atHzmOpSf_t3HQrw\"",
 "nickname": "Dahnark",
 "occupation": "Student",
 "skills": "Video Editing",
 "birthday": "1989-04-19",
 "gender": "male",
 "urls": [
  {
   "value": "http://www.facebook.com/javiersegoviacordoba",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "Javier Segovia Córdoba"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://twitter.com/dahnark",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "Javier Segovia Córdoba"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://youtube.com/thedahnark",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "Dahnark"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://es.linkedin.com/pub/javier-segovia-cordoba/59/27/340/",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "Javier Segovia Córdoba"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://desarrollador-android.com",
   "type": "contributor",
   "label": "Desarrollador Android"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://desarrollador-android.com",
   "type": "contributor",
   "label": "Desarrollador Android"
  }
 ],
 "objectType": "person",
 "id": "116491025947756017022",
 "displayName": "Javier Segovia Córdoba",
 "name": {
  "familyName": "Segovia Córdoba",
  "givenName": "Javier"
 },
 "relationshipStatus": "in_a_relationship",
 "url": "https://plus.google.com/+JavierSegoviaCordoba",
 "image": {
  "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-LEwBpvgLyOM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAHJM/CbQbbI7w1Bc/photo.jpg?sz=50",
  "isDefault": false
 },
 "organizations": [
  {
   "name": "University of Cádiz, España",
   "title": "Aerospace Engineering",
   "type": "school",
   "startDate": "2012",
   "primary": true
  },
  {
   "name": "University of Granada, España",
   "title": "Physical education",
   "type": "school",
   "startDate": "2008",
   "endDate": "2011",
   "primary": false
  },
  {
   "name": "IES Padre Poveda of Guadix, España",
   "title": "Technology",
   "type": "school",
   "startDate": "1999",
   "endDate": "2007",
   "primary": false
  },
  {
   "name": "Medina Olmos of Guadix, España",
   "title": "Elementary School",
   "type": "school",
   "primary": false
  }
 ],
 "placesLived": [
  {
   "value": "Cádiz",
   "primary": true
  },
  {
   "value": "Guadix"
  }
 ],
 "isPlusUser": true,
 "circledByCount": 89,
 "verified": false,
 "cover": {
  "layout": "banner",
  "coverPhoto": {
   "url": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-fHOV1IEH9D8/Uo6H1_3Yl3I/AAAAAAAASa8/kfbkrAcRjxY/s630-fcrop64=1,284258f39908ad6a/20130810_202949.jpg",
   "height": 705,
   "width": 940
  },
  "coverInfo": {
   "topImageOffset": -197,
   "leftImageOffset": 0
  }
 }
}
```

And this is the code to get the strings:

```
// get json string from url
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String firstname = json.getString("kind");
            String lastname = json.getString("etag");
```

How can I solve this? The errors are in this last two last strings...

Usually the json object has an array just before, but this not, I writting bad the getStrings methods?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad english

Comment: `getJSONFromUrl` this fails to fetch your json. There might be some errors when fetching the url, post your full logcat. And that method's code too.

Comment: I tried to get other json objects and I got all. Is the public API. For example: I can get this json object and put its strings in my strings/textviews without problem, http://demo.codeofaninja.com/tutorials/json-example-with-php/index.php

Comment: I followed this tutorial for doing the asynctask to get json objects: https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/11/android-json-parsing-tutorial.html, it works perfectly except with google+ public api. You can check my code in that link

Comment: What about errors before the logcat you posted? Are there any?

Comment: I have added all errors.

Comment: You're probably getting an incorrect response from the server. You need to modify JsonParser to get it printed (if it's not yet in the logcat).

Comment: How do I to do that? you can check my JsonParser in that tutorial, I dont understand why work with some urls and not with others :/

Comment: Can you post the url you are trying to fetch from?

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/%2Bjaviersegoviacordoba?key=AIzaSyAh2SShUH7nud798_Gg7gGnXygJillC7i0

Comment: True. Works via browser but not via android. Returns: "Not Found".

Comment: I tried browser and android api (you are using android api). Same error both. In key features, all apps and references are allowed.

Comment: Something must be wrong with calling google api with this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that the parser from your tutorial doesn't quite work with Google APIs (at least the one you've given). However, simple parser from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4308662/3249477), does work.

Edit your JsonParser.java to:

```
public class JsonParser {

    public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            String jsonText = readAll(rd);
            return new JSONObject(jsonText);
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }

    private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) cp);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

And call it from your AsyncTask like this:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    JSONObject json = null;
    try {
        json = JsonParser.readJsonFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);
        // Storing each json item in variable
        String kind = json.getString("kind");
        String etag = json.getString("etag");

        Log.e("TAG", "Kind: " + kind);
        Log.e("TAG", "etag: " + etag);
    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```