# Parsing Multiple (Thousands) of JSON objects from a url in Java

Tags: java, json

I have to deal with multiple thousands of JSON objects that I am getting from a url in Java.  I tried using the usual JSON code I have but I get the error `Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 2 [character 3 line 1]`

Because there are no curly braces present in the JSON data only square brackets around each JSON object.

I would appreciate any help I can get with this.

BTW the code I was trying to use was the code posted in the highest answer here:[simplest way to read json from a URL in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308554/simplest-way-to-read-json-from-a-url-in-java)

Thanks

Comment: The end result of dealing with this data will be storing each object in its own row in a MySQL database.

Comment: Well, then that isn't valid format, is it?

Comment: It is what I am provided with and what I am forced to use unfortunately.

Comment: It is the JSON data provided by the MailChimp list function.  It treats every individual subscriber as a new JSON object.

Comment: Please post an example of the input here and the code you used to process it.

Comment: An additional piece of information is that there is one object per line with each line being separated by \n

Comment: so the json is in the format of [{...}, {...}, ...]?

Comment: If so, you need to be using a JSONArray, not a JSONObject.

Comment: There are no curly brackets whatsoever in the JSON

Comment: Okay, So I changed to JSONArray and ` System.out.println(json.toString());` Prints the header line but I cannot use the json.get function

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the correct method for handling this.

Once I treat the data as JSON Arrays it works fine.
I then specify the field I want by number reference rather that name. For example:
`System.out.println(json.toString());
        System.out.println(json.get(2));`

will print the header row then print the second field of the header row.

To process the next object, I presume a loop advancing the line number on each recursion would work fine.

Comment: So if someone could point out how to deal with the multiple arrays I would be greatful

Comment: I find it very unlikely that MailChimp would return anything but syntactically correct JSON. I think you are deserializing the JSON incorrectly.

Comment: Your right, I figured it out, I was just the way I handling the data.