# java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format when trying to load url openstream java

Tags: java, json, inputstream

I am trying to load JSON from a URL, as necessary in another answer here 
[simplest way to read json from a URL in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308554/simplest-way-to-read-json-from-a-url-in-java)

However, I am trying to use the answer given by Roland and this by itself does not work. The JSON library is working and imported correctly, but I am getting the following error when trying to open the URL stream:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(SSLSocketFactory.java:248)
at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:255)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.createSocket(HttpsClient.java:405)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:162)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
at JsonReader.readJsonFromUrl(JsonReader.java:24)
at JsonReader.main(JsonReader.java:36)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1617)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:96)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:122)
at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:332)
at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:289)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:85)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:62)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:57)
at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:972)
... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:225)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getCacertsKeyStore(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.getDefaultTrustManager(SSLContextImpl.java:767)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:733)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1595)
... 14 more
```

If anyone knows what is causing this issue any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit - Adding the original code from the link...

```
package so4308554;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonReader {

  private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552");
    System.out.println(json.toString());
    System.out.println(json.get("id"));
  }
}
```

Comment: where is the code man ?

Comment: Your problem with https, not posted code. Maybe broken cacerts or wrong custom truststore passed via -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore caused this error

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there is a simple fix for this or a reinstall necessary?

Comment: I have removed the Java cacerts from within /etc/ssl/certs/java and run the update script /usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates

I now get a different error: 
**_Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty_**

Comment: You didn't specify what Java version you are using, what OS, it is very important. No one can reproduce this issue and answer you without this information. I suppose your java setup is broken, and i see only one sane way to fix it - download jdk from oracle.com, install it and run your program with that jdk.