# HttpsURLConnection to JSONObject convert

Tags: java, json

```
try {         

   url = new URL(https_url);
   HttpsURLConnection posts = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I convert the HttpsURLConnection **posts** object to JSONObject? Thanks in advance. :)

> **Answer: [using the mvn org.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308554/simplest-way-to-read-json-from-a-url-in-java)**

Comment: Solution depends on library you are using...

Answer (score 1):

1. Look for a JSON-library (there are dozens out there, from fancy stuff like GSON, Jackson, etc. to more lightweight ones).
2. Read its documentation.
3. Pass the InputStream directly, wrap it in a reader or read it as a String, depending on the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `GSon` to work with `Json`, though I doubt you really need put to jSon `posts` object. The other case if you want to put `HttpsURLConnection` response to json. By the way you can create jSon object with plain string like:
"

```
String json = "{"+"hello"+":"+"hello I am json Object"+"}";
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a mistake here. The object that you are creating is a connection object. There is no JSON to extract. If you want to get the JSON from the URL , this is sample code below.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```