# Any method of passing the Json data in URL format using JSONObject?

Tags: java, json

I create a java URL class which contain my Json data and have some function to obtain back my json data for doing some data comparison, I found out it's might not support by JSONObject for passing the data into the JSONObject. Do I need to use JSONArray in my case because my JSON data have array structure as well?

```
     try
           {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject (); 
            obj.readJsonFromUrl(theUrl);
            System.out.println(obj.toString());
           }

       catch(MalformedURLException e)
       {
           System.out.print("your problem here ...1");
       }
   }
   else
   {
       System.out.print("Can't Connect");
   }
```

I am sure that this is the place give me the error message because it return me this error in my compiler

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method readJsonFromUrl(URL) is undefined for the type JSONObject
```

there are also some warning message for that the JSONObject readJsonFromUrl method 
    `private static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(URL theUrl) throws IOException, JSONException {` 
Anyone can provide me the explaination of how the JSON data work in java? I saw quite number of Java class for JSON which make me confuse for it such as JSONObject, JSONArray , JSONValue. I search some information online but I also not very clear about it since I am very new to JSON data processing 
 This is my sample json data and the data I need is scan_result only

```
{  
   "data_id":"a71a3c2588c6472bb4daea41a0b58835",
   "file_info":{  
      "display_name":"",
      "file_size":242,
      "file_type":"Not available",
      "file_type_description":"Not available",
      "md5":"aa69ba384f22d0dc0551ace2fbb9ad55",
      "sha1":"09ceb54e65df3d3086b222e8643acffe451a6e8a",
      "sha256":"dcb46d6ae2a187f789c12f19c44bbe4b9a43bd200a3b306d5e9c1fcf811dc430",
      "upload_timestamp":"2016-11-18T09:09:08.390Z"
   },
   "process_info":{  
      "blocked_reason":"",
      "file_type_skipped_scan":false,
      "post_processing":{  
         "actions_failed":"",
         "actions_ran":"",
         "converted_destination":"",
         "converted_to":"",
         "copy_move_destination":""
      },
      "profile":"File scan",
      "progress_percentage":100,
      "result":"Allowed",
      "user_agent":""
   },
   "scan_results":{  
      "data_id":"a71a3c2588c6472bb4daea41a0b58835",
      "progress_percentage":100,
      "scan_all_result_a":"No Threat Detected",
      "scan_all_result_i":0,
      "scan_details":{  
         "Ahnlab":{  
            "def_time":"2016-11-08T15:00:00.000Z",
            "location":"local",
            "scan_result_i":0,
            "scan_time":1,
            "threat_found":""
         },
         "Avira":{  
            "def_time":"2016-11-08T00:00:00.000Z",
            "location":"local",
            "scan_result_i":0,
            "scan_time":133,
            "threat_found":""
         },
         "ClamAV":{  
            "def_time":"2016-11-08T10:28:00.000Z",
            "location":"local",
            "scan_result_i":0,
            "scan_time":94,
            "threat_found":""
         },
         "ESET":{  
            "def_time":"2016-11-08T00:00:00.000Z",
            "location":"local",
            "scan_result_i":0,
            "scan_time":38,
            "threat_found":""
         }
      },
      "start_time":"2016-11-18T09:09:08.405Z",
      "total_avs":4,
      "total_time":250
   },
   "vulnerability_info":{  

   }
}
```

Comment: are you sure readJsonFromUrl method is having inside JSONOBject class?

Comment: @SpringLearner - I try change to getJsonObject and it's show me the same error message. would you might recommend any suitable method in JSONObject ?

Comment: Are you referring to the `javax.json.JSONObject` in JavaEE7?

Comment: @HeartBreakKID show us the sample JSON ? After that we can tell you the exact way

Comment: @isuru-buddhika - I am referring this org.json.JSONObject;

Comment: @SpringLearner - I updated my question with my JSON structure, hope you can provide me some suggestion how to deal with my data

Comment: @HeartBreakKID try with getjsonobject("scan_results")

Comment: Do you want to read/write/handle json? Is there any restrictions of using a library?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass json in url, you can pass it in body. Writing Json to [stream body](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsonp003.htm#BABHAHIA) and post it using regular [java method](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/).
Here is oracle [community url](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html) of explanation of your problem.

Required Jar can be downloaded from [here](https://jsonp.java.net/download.html).

Test Code Follows:

```
   URL url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=java&type=post");
         try (InputStream is = url.openStream();
              JsonReader rdr = Json.createReader(is)) {

             JsonObject obj = rdr.readObject();
             JsonArray results = obj.getJsonArray("data");
             for (JsonObject result : results.getValuesAs(JsonObject.class)){
                 System.out.print(result.getJsonObject("from").getString("name"));
                 System.out.print(": ");
                System.out.println(result.getString("message", ""));
               System.out.println("-----------");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308554/simplest-way-to-read-json-from-a-url-in-java), there are many ways to solve this. Either you have to implement the read, parse operations yourself (@Roland Illig 's answer)

```
//you have to implement the readJSON method 
InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
try {
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
  String jsonText = readAll(rd);
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
  return json;
} finally {
  is.close();
}
```

Or you could use a library. The most well-known and widely used libraries are [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs) and [gson](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md).
The big picture is that you try to "map" your json Object to a class.

You have your json file:

`{
   "id":1,
   "name":"eirini",
   "hobbies":["music","philosophy","football"]
}`

and a class that represents this file and will store the values (depending on the library that you use there might be different requirements, for example getters, setters etc..)

```
public class Person {
   public int id;
   public String name;
   public List<String> hobbies = new ArrayList<String>();

   public String toString() {
       return name +" has the id: " + id + " the following hobbies" + hobbies.get(0) + " " + hobbies.get(2); 
   }
}
```

Finally in your main method:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    InputStream input = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(FILE); //read your file. There are many ways to achieve this.
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // just need one
    Person eirini = mapper.readValue(input, Person.class);
    System.out.println(eirini.toString());
```