# how to do a get request using java spark

Tags: java, json, get, spark-java

I have to access third part  api using java spark

get request
http://41.1.1.92:3000/nodes

I just want to know how to access this api using java spark and return the response

when i try to access api  response is as shown below

```
  [
      {
        "host": "ip-133472-334341-134341-4834",
        "ip": "5342.1344.1344.9342",
        "status": "Healthy",
        "containers": "8 (8 Running, 0 Paused, 0 Stopped)",
        "updatedAt": "2017-01-17T06:34:10Z"
      }
    ]
```

Please point to document where i can learn more about it

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question is not related to Spark-Java and just a java question. for more information:  [simplest way to read json from a URL in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308554/simplest-way-to-read-json-from-a-url-in-java)