# How to parse json from website with java?

Tags: java, json, parsing

here is a link : https://api.nanopool.org/v1/etn/balance/etnkGqH26XNVZ9cJv7jh95Dwj7LYPupYX5F5QVf85icHXq2sRJcXSxDT6SL4gD2Vn1WBKi5wqd9x5En2LLmDhnKs8pqrcM75VJ to a json file and i would like to get the data on java.
So how can i download the file or parsing it directly from internet ?

Thank you

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simplest way to read json from a URL in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308554/simplest-way-to-read-json-from-a-url-in-java)

Comment: Try Spring Boot. Go to https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/json
Library contains support for HTTP requests and easily converts json directly to models (objects).

Answer (score 0):

Here is link to a tutorial to do it with Jersey 2 http://www.baeldung.com/jersey-jax-rs-client.

You can fetch the data and deserialize it to POJO class with the library.

There are another ways like Spring RestClient, RestEasy etc. also to do so.

It should not be a problem.