# Getting a json element URL net beans

Tags: java, json, url, netbeans

I am trying to get an element from a JSON URL, but nothing seem to work. I tried to create an object to store the response, and then access it. It didn't work. Here is my code:

```
public class JavaApplication4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String line;

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output from running that code:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

I want to get the individual key values. For example, I want to get the value of "title".

Comment: Try Following this url: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21964051/9991072. I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several third-party tools to do what you want, but you can also use Java EE's [Java API for JSON Processing](https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/) (sometimes confusingly known as JSON-P) to process a URL's JSON data, without knowing the structure of that data.

Here's the code, which uses the code in the OP as a starting point:

```
package com.unthreading;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.stream.JsonParser;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder jsonData = new StringBuilder();
        URL url = new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonData.append(line);
            }
        }
        new App().processUnknownJson(jsonData.toString());
    }

    private void processUnknownJson(String jsonData) {
        System.out.println("jsonData:" + jsonData);
        JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(new StringReader(jsonData));
        while (parser.hasNext()) {
            JsonParser.Event event = parser.next();
            switch (event) {
            case START_ARRAY:
            case END_ARRAY:
            case START_OBJECT:
            case END_OBJECT:
            case VALUE_FALSE:
            case VALUE_NULL:
            case VALUE_TRUE:
                System.out.println(event.toString());
                break;
            case KEY_NAME:
                System.out.print(event.toString() + " " + parser.getString() + " - ");
                break;
            case VALUE_STRING:
            case VALUE_NUMBER:
                System.out.println(event.toString() + " " + parser.getString());
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Unexpected event: " + event.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output, showing the JSON string returned from the URL, and the results from parsing that string into key/value pairs:

```
jsonData:{  "userId": 1,  "id": 1,  "title": "delectus aut autem",  "completed": false}
START_OBJECT
KEY_NAME userId - VALUE_NUMBER 1
KEY_NAME id - VALUE_NUMBER 1
KEY_NAME title - VALUE_STRING delectus aut autem
KEY_NAME completed - VALUE_FALSE
END_OBJECT
```

The parsing code is taken from an Oracle example: [Reading JSON Data Using a Parser](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLPRG/java-api-for-json-proc.htm#WLPRG1064).

I created the application as a simple Maven project using this `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.unthreading</groupId>
    <artifactId>myjsonparser</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>myjsonparser</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>[1.1.2,)</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```