# How to get currency from Json?

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to get the currency's from Json using Gson but my method returns null. The currency value should be a BigDecimal object and I want to get the value using currency symbol as method argument.

I've created a method rateFromApi(String currency) shown below. I've read the API and from what I understood the line

```
rate = rootObj.get(currency).getAsBigDecimal();
```

should assign to variable rate the value to which currency name is mapped. 
I found similar problem already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308554/simplest-way-to-read-json-from-a-url-in-java)
But still I do not understand what am I doing wrong in my code.

```
//fields and method in class responsible for getting data from Json
private final String sURL = "http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key...";
    private URL url = new URL(sURL);
    private URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
    private JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();

public BigDecimal rateFromAPI(String currency) throws IOException {
        request.connect();
        BigDecimal rate;
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
        JsonObject rootObj = root.getAsJsonObject();
        return rate = rootObj.get(currency).getAsBigDecimal();
    }


//expression in method main
//indicate which exactly currency has to be taken from Json
Zloty pln1 = eur.convertToPln(ratesGetter.rateFromAPI("PLN"));
```

I thought the Json will be parsed and by using the line `rootObj.get(currency).getAsBigDecimal();`
the value which is mapped to the currency name will be assigned to variable rate as BigDecimal but the result I'm getting is NullPointerException in return line.

Comment: You might want to redact the access key.

Comment: and then include a dummy json that you would get returned if you actually accessed the API.

Comment: Open http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=<redacted>&format=1. Look: it doesn't have any "PLN" property. It has a "rates" property, which itself has a "PLN" property.

Comment: Are you sure it's `get(currency)`, and not `get("currency")`? If you've posted a snippet, please make sure it's a [mcve], by testing it to ensure it works and demonstrates the issue. Ideally, embed some sample JSON as a string literal, instead of depending on a network call.

Comment: @Nic Hartley I'm pretty sure it should be `get(currency)` instead of `get("currency")` because I'm passing String in this method  somewhere else like here
`eur.convertToPln(ratesGetter.rateFromAPI("PLN"));`

Comment: So it's not an MCVE, then, because this won't compile as-is (there's no `currency` variable defined in the snippet). Please write a [mcve] and [edit] your question to have it, instead of a snippet.

Comment: Thank you all for help, I think I found the problem, as @JB Nizet suggested I had to get to "PLN" property instead "rates". One additional line of code in method `ratesFromAPI()` solved the issue.This line is 
`JsonObject ratesList = rootObj.getAsJsonObject("rates");` 
and then 
`return ratesList.get(currency).getAsBigDecimal();`